# Tracking Network request with zombie.js in node.js

Tags: node.js, zombie.js

I'm currently looking for a way to track all requests made from a Website in zombie.js. The idea is to get all information about loaded content (eg. tracking pixel for ads, analytics tags, images, css ...). Basically the Network Monitor from the dev Tools in a headless browser.

I'm currently stuck at this point:

```
var Browser = require("zombie");
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
var browser = new Browser();

browser.visit(url, function(err) {
    for (var i = browser.resources.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        console.log(browser.resources[i].request.url)
    }
})
```

This is probably the most basic Set Up and will not track anything except of some .js request. Also I can't track loaded files which are loaded by some external Script. Best example is the Google Tagmanager which will "hide" all files which are loaded by the Tag Manager.

Would be great if somebody would have a idea how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Daniel

Answer (score 2):

What you want to find out is called Resources, and you can access them via browser.resources, like

```
browser.visit(url).then(function(){
    console.log(browser.resources); // array with downloaded resources
});
```

You can also creates pipes to monitor the resources being downloaded real-time:

```
browser.pipeline.addHandler(function(browser, request, response){
    console.log(request, response);
    return response;
});
browser.visit(url).then(function(){
    console.log('successful visit');
});
```